# android:set size of indicator in expandable list view

Tags: android, expandablelistview, indicator

I am making an app in which i have to use image of group indicator when when applied it shows enlargrd image .Can anyone help me how to set indicator image in expandable list view .Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a custom drawable is probably what you need. You cant toy with the in built indicator. have a look at [this](http://android-adda.blogspot.in/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html). The group_indicator.xml at the bottom of that page is an example of a custom indicator. You just add this drawable to the android:groupindicator value of you expandablelistview element. This way you can control the indicator behavious and size and with aa few tweaks also hide the indicator if there are no children in the group.

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
        <item android:state_empty="true" android:drawable="@drawable/arrowright">  
        <item android:state_expanded="true" android:drawable="@drawable/arrowdown">  
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrowright">  
        </item></item></item>  
    </selector>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following code may be helpful

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:state_empty="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item
            android:left="20dp"
            android:right="-30dp"
            android:top="120dp"
            android:bottom="10dp"
            android:drawable="@drawable/panier_plus">
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>

<item android:state_expanded="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item
            android:left="20dp"
            android:right="-30dp"
            android:top="120dp"
            android:bottom="10dp"
            android:drawable="@drawable/panier_minus"
             >
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
</selector>
```

Comment: You're missing the bottom </selector>

Answer (score 0):

This version uses the latest ic_keyboard_arrow vector icons (24dp):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_empty="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:top="24dp"
                android:bottom="24dp"
                android:drawable="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_up">
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item android:state_expanded="false">
        <layer-list>
            <item
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:top="24dp"
                android:bottom="24dp"
                android:drawable="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_up">
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item android:state_expanded="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:top="24dp"
                android:bottom="24dp"
                android:drawable="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down">
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```